# Make errors: "ar: creating ../lib/libmgr.a"

Tags: bash, makefile, stderr

I have a bash script that performs makes and then aborts when a make writes to stderr. The code is like this:

```
make all 2>${ERROR_FILE}
ERR=$(cat ${ERROR_FILE})
if [ ! -z "${ERR}" ];
then
    abort "Halted because of errors in make $1: ${ERR}"
fi
```

However, make writes the following to the file:

```
ar: creating ../lib/libmgr.a
ar: creating ../lib/libnet.a
ar: creating ../lib/libeoc.a
ar: creating ../lib/libdvr.a
ar: creating ../lib/libmsg.a
ar: creating ../lib/liblgc.a
ar: creating ../lib/libshm.a
ar: creating ../lib/libsys.a
ar: creating ../lib/librsk.a
ar: creating ../lib/librep.a
ar: creating ../lib/libmdl.a
ar: creating ../lib/libmdb.a
ar: creating ../lib/libdat.a
ar: creating ../lib/libchs.a
```

What does this mean? Are these errors? If not, why are they written to stderr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't look like errors, they look like messages from [ar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29). Why do you stop if the std err file is nonzero? Do you want to stop on warnings too? If not, you may want to stop based on the status of the make command (a non zero $? value after the make command indicates error).

Comment: I will add to the above that `ERR=$(cat ${ERROR_FILE})` is crazy. What you want is to see if the file has any contents. This is better done with test: `if [ ! -s "${ERROR_FILE}" ] ; then echo abort, size 0 file ; fi`

Comment: This project has no warnings so I guess I have to abort at warnings as well. Thanks for your help. I'm now just not aborting if everything starts with "ar:". @Sorpigal you have a point, but I do use the variable $ERR.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-c` flag with `ar` to suppress the diagnostic message that is written to standard error by default when an archive is created. For example:

```
$ ar -cruv libfoo.a foo.o bar.o baz.o
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @skjaidev. Additionally, you can also be more specific about what you are looking for in your ERR variable. One approach is

**Edit : changed references from ar to make**

```
 make ....
 make_rc=$?
 case "${ERR}" in
    *[Ee][Rr][Rr][Oo][Rr]* )
        # real error, modify or duplicate as needed
        echo "real error" >&2
        exit ${make_rc}
    ;;
    *[Ww][Aa][Rr][Nn]* )
        # modify or duplicate as needed for various warning msgs
        echo "real warning $(echo "$ERR" | grep -i warn) >&2
        # exit ?
    ;;
    * )
      # other stuff
    ;;
 esac
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand much of it, but it looks like you (wrongly) assume that I'm calling ar. That's something make does.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Are you saying you don't understand the `case ... esac` construct? `*[Ee][Rr][Rr][Oo][Rr]*` is a shell regular expression that will match any 'error', 'ERROR' 'Error', 'ERror', etc in you `${ERR}` variable.